# Disabling a item in the database instead of deleting it

Tags: django, postgresql, django-admin

Is there a way of disabling the item in the database instead of deleting it.

Any one with any idea , Do reply

Comment: Define "item". Some objects can be disabled. Triggers, for instance. But I see from your comments further down, you are referring to values / rows of tables. So no, no standard way to "disable" those.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i guess it depends on what you mean by 'disabling'. you could add a `BooleanField` called e.g. `disabled`, and then filter your queries (probably best done via a [custom manager](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/managers/#custom-managers)) so instead of

```
Mymodel.objects.all()
```

do

```
Mymodel.objects.filter(disabled=False).all()
```

Comment: thing is i wanted to delete a item in the database. but i has got foreign key relations with some other items, so i thought if there is a way i can make that entry inactive.

Comment: and if i add  a boolean field to the present model, the only way i can  see the changes is when i syncdb, and to do that is deleting the table right?

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.on_delete may be worth a look

Comment: @ChingChong You are solving the wrong task then. You just need `ForeignKey` with `null=True, blank=True`, and you can delete the item without any problem.

Comment: for managing changes to models without deleting and re-creating, have a look at django south http://south.aeracode.org/

Answer (score 1):

Not in SQL. What you probably would be ending up doing to solve the problem is either

- Moving the "disabled" values to another table, either by a trigger or stored procedure

or

- Adding an 'active' flag to the table with default value 1 and setting it to 0 instead of deleting. That would require an extra condition on every query (and active=1) that does not want to query disabled records.

Answer (score 0):

You can set a field in the table which you set if the row is valid or unset if the row is deactivated.